# Xubuntu 13.04 64-bit, mountall error, can't boot

Tags: xubuntu

Last night my laptop froze up and I had to do a hard shutdown. Now Xubuntu won't boot up. I was getting the error message "mountall: error while loading shared libraries: libply-boot-client.so.2: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error". I tried 'Advanced options for Ubuntu> recovery mode' and selected fsck but received the same error.

I searched for an answer with no success. An old post suggested using a live boot to mount and chroot the partition and update mountall but that didn't work. I now get a blinking cursor when trying to do a normal boot.

I even tried to reinstall plymouth but received a message about breaking it. I was getting the error "plymouth: error while loading shared libraries: libply.so.2: cannot open shared object files: Input/output error" beforehand but that stopped.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like a disk drive problem. You can boot from a live CD and use `smartctl` to confirm.

Comment: @ James Fu

I used 'sudo smartctl -Hc /dev/sda' and it's said "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED".

Comment: @PJ That's good news. After chroot-ing, can you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libplymouth2` and report back?